# Optimal function existence? what is it?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oc.optimization-and-control, nonlinear-optimization

It's a problem abstracted from a real engineering project.
I want to find the best curve $y=y(x)$, $x \in [0,1]$: $y$ doesn't have to be a continuous function.
The constraint is 
$$
L=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{y^3} dx =\text{const.},
$$ which represents the energy consumption of the system.
The objective function is
$$
J[y]=\int_{0}^{1} \left[ L \int_{0}^{z} \frac{1}{y^4} dx - \int_{0}^{z} \frac{1}{y^3} dx  \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{y^4} dx \right] dz
$$ 
which instead represents the thrust force of the system.
The meaning of this question is find out what's the maximum force exerted by a specific system when its energy consumption is limited.

Questions

- Does the objective function has a finite maximum?
- If the objective function has a finite maximum, what's the expression of $y$?
- If the objective function does not have a finite maximum, what's the expression of $y$?

Comment: A possible condition can be added $y(1)=1$.

Comment: Is $y$ positive, or not necessarily?

Comment: From the view of engineering, y must be greater than 0.

Answer (score 1):

By introducing a few more variables and constraints you can also write it into a form which can partially be solved with [Pontryagin's maximum principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pontryagin%27s_maximum_principle):

\begin{align}
\max_y & \int_0^1 L_1\,x_1(t) - L_2\,x_2(t)\,dt \\
\text{s.t.}\, & \frac{d\,x_1(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{y^4(t)},\ \frac{d\,x_2(t)}{dt} = \frac{1}{y^3(t)}, \\
& x_1(0) = 0,\ x_2(0) = 0, \\
& x_1(1) = L_2,\ x_2(1) = L_1.
\end{align}

After solving this problem one would still be free to choose $L_2$, but this would just be a scalar optimization problem, which should be easier to solve. The resulting Hamiltonian associated with the problem can be written as

$$
H(x,y,\lambda) = \frac{\lambda_1}{y^4} + \frac{\lambda_2}{y^3} + L_2\,x_2 - L_1\,x_1
$$

The dynamics of the co-states are given by

$$
\frac{d\,\lambda_1(t)}{dt} = L_1, \\ \frac{d\,\lambda_2(t)}{dt} = -L_2.
$$

The expression for $y$ can be found by maximizing the Hamiltonian. However, depending on the values of $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ this does not necessarily have to satisfy the solution $H_y = 0$, with $H_y$ the partial derivative of $H$ with respect to $y$.

Comment: Thank you, this is the right answer. I checked it with numerical methods.